# How much Tablespace we need to create for Oracle schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces

How is the optimum number of tablespace we need to create in an Oracle schema ?
One for data and one for index ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean how many tablespaces do you need to create? We dont create tablespaces on schema. We create schema(user) objects on tablespace.

Comment: Yes , if we need to create only one Tablespace by schema or one for data and other for index ?

Comment: Yes, you can create two tablespaces, one for table data and another for Indexes.

Comment: You don't have to have schema-specific tablespaces, but you may want to for application separation. [And you don't have to have separate tablespaces for data and indexes](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1463404632043). You may have legitimate reasons to do both, but there is no one answer for your general question.

Comment: The optimum number is the number of tablespaces you need according to your requirements for managing hard disk space. What are those requirements?

Comment: You need SYSTEM, SYSAUX, TEMP, UNDO and USERS. You can run a db with just these. Is it is good idea? yes and no because it depends on your requirements. You can technically out everything else in USERS. Definition of "optimum" is different for everyone so you get to choose for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "rule of thumb" but it really depends upon your hardware configuration.

With different tablespace for every Schema or Index and Data you can differentiate based on the cost or the speed of the disk space.